# Доступ к ListView во фрагменте Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

В Basic Activity сделал кастомный ListView. Всё отлично работало и заполнялось. Потребовалось запихнуть этот ListView в один из фрагментов Bottom Navigation Activity. Проблема заключается в том, что из класса MainActivity (в котором происходит создание этих фрагментов) я не могу получить доступ к ListView во фрагменте

Код создания фрагментов в MainActivity

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

В BasicActivity я использовал такой код:

```
lessionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lessionList);
    // создаем адаптер
    LessionAdapter lessionAdapter = new LessionAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, lession);
    // устанавливаем адаптер
    lessionList.setAdapter(lessionAdapter);
```

Могу ли я как-то из MainActivity получить доступ к ListView в HomeFragment? Или как мне его заполнить из самого фрагмента?

Comment: Для каких целей вам это нужно? Что вы там храните

Comment: Свой класс, состоящий из 5 стринговых объектов. Делаю расписание, где будут отображаться название дисциплины, номер аудитории, время проведения, фамилия преподавателя, тема занятия.

Comment: а для чего вам доступ из Activity? У вас же есть Fragment для этого

Comment: Я не могу отобразить свой ListView во фрагменте. Видимо использую не правильный адаптер. Не смог найти информацию по этому поводу.

Comment: Все то же самое, что и в Activity

Comment: Только нужно будет искать элемент в OnViewCreated
lessionList = view.findViewById()